# Rocket.Chat Iframe integration: browser navigation failure

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, oauth, rocket.chat

I am integrating Rocket.Chat to our existing web application, which has a large user base. After successfull Rocket.Chat Keycloak integration (SSO), it was decided to inject chat to the existing application using available iframe integration since it allows sending commands for authentication and simplifies Rocket.Chat events handling.

The **actual problem** is the fact that, **iframe integration breaks site navigation**, i.e. klicking browser's back button doesn't navigate to the previous page. Possible solutions available on SO are unfortunately not helping.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you found any solution ?

Comment: @hussainnayani, no, unfortunately, I didn't